# how to open document in browser with angular?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a table with in it documents with their filelocation ie url. What can I use /do to open this document in the browser ? Or when this is an ms office file in word or excel?

Answer (score 1):

A quickwin but probably expensive solution is to upload or your files to googledrive by API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) with restrictive permissions (a unique authkey per file) then you iframe the google drive's url in your webapp.

This is expensive as if you have many users/files, you'll need more space on google drive.

If your users are signed in using google, then it's better for security as instead of an authkey you can handle permissions by email.

Otherwise, you can use some javascript word/excel editor like http://webodf.org/.

Hope it helps!

Younes for Wishtack.com